Definition of 'proper lorentz transformation' being having positive determinant or preserving the orientation of spatial axes
In the book I am reading, the proper Lorentz transformations are defined as Lorentz transformations (hereinafter LT) with $\det \Lambda =1$. It states that:

The proper Lorentz transformations preserve the orientation of spatial axes.

But afterwards, the book adds that:

For the proper Lorentz transformations the condition $\det \Lambda =1$ is necessary, but not sufficient. (...) An example is the space-time inversion described by $\Lambda =-I$, which is an improper transformation, but still satisfies $\det \Lambda =1$.


For the improper Lorentz transformations, the condition $\det \Lambda =-1$ is sufficient, but not necessary.

I am wondering if the definition of proper LT is LTs with positive determinants or LTs that preserve the orientation of spatial axes. It seems that the book has defined proper LT as $\det \Lambda =1$ while using it as the second definition. The book also says that:

The fact that the condition $\det \Lambda =\pm1$ does not select unequivocally the proper and improper LTs is due to the indefinite metric on Minkowski space.

Which needs more explanation.
Plus, what is the definition of "preserving the orientation of spatial (or any other types) axes" if it is not $\det \Lambda =1$?

The definition of a proper Lorentz transformation is that its determinant is 1.  This, by itself, is not sufficient to guarantee that the orientation of the spatial axes are preserved; to guarantee that, we need to bring in the concept of orthochronous Lorentz transformations, which are defined to be transformations that preserve the direction of time.  A proper orthochronous Lorentz transformation is guaranteed to preserve the orientation of the spatial axes, while a proper non-orthochronous Lorentz transformation is guaranteed to change the orientation of the spatial axes.
If you have a transformation that transforms the spatial axes and the time axis separately, and doesn't mix the two, then that transformation will preserve the orientation of the spatial axes if and only if the part of the matrix that acts on the spatial components has a determinant of 1.
